# Atom エディタで、ソースコードのアウトライン表示のできるパッケージ

Tags: atom-editor

Atom エディタで、秀丸の「アウトライン解析」に近いパッケージはないでしょうか？

- [Atom Editor](https://atom.io/)
- [秀丸のアウトライン機能](http://hide.maruo.co.jp/software/hidemaru8/outline.html)

### やりたいこと

- アウトライン解析の「解析文字対象」を自分で設定できること。
- アウトライン結果が、ツリー表示で表示されること。
- アウトラインの解析レベルは３レベル程度設定できること。

### 探している理由

これまでずっと開発で秀丸を使ってきましたが、秀丸を使っている理由がこの「アウトライン機能」があったためでしたので、もし Atom にその機能があるのなら、こちらに乗り換えようと思った次第です。

以上になります。Atomでこの機能に近いご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、何卒、ご返答よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

Atom エディタビギナーです。

近い機能としては symbols-tree-view というパッケージがあります。
https://atom.io/packages/symbols-tree-view

提供されているオプションではそこまでカスタマイズはできなさそうです。
このパッケージを参考に自作することはできるかもしれません。